# Transposing many columns in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, transpose

All , 
there are a lot of questions on transpose , but could not find the best solution.So posting another transpose question

My Data is this format

```
> Customer| Status_A|Status_B|Status_C  
> 111|New | Null|New   
> 222|Old | Old |New   
> 333|Null| New |New
```

I want the result in this format

```
>Customer   Parameter   Status  
>111    A   New  
>111    B   Null  
>111    C   New  
>222    A   Old  
>222    B   Old  
>222    C   New  
>333    A   Null   
>333    B   New   
>333    C   New
```

Note - 
1)I have 50 columns like this
2)I do not really need the rows with null in the resultant data

Looking for the most efficient solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a giant `union all`:

```
select customer, 'A' as parameter, status_a as status from t where status_a is not null union all
select customer, 'B' as parameter, status_b from t where status_b is not null union all
. . .
```

This can be a pain to type, so I would suggest that you generate the code in a spreadsheet or using another SQL query.

The above require scanning the table once for each column.  Sometimes a faster approach uses `cross join`:

```
select t.customer, p.parameter,
       (case p.parameter
            where 'a' then status_a
            where 'b' then status_b
            . . .
        end) as status
from t cross join
     (select 'a' as parameter union all
      select 'b' union all
      . . .
     ) p;
```

To eliminate `NULL`s make this a subquery and use `where status is not NULL`.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to use hive functions like Explode ? Want to avoid giant Union all or Case whens if possible